# Find the index of the word in sentence even if it matches partially (fuzzy)

Tags: python, regex, string, fuzzy-search

I need to find the start index of a word in a sentence even if it matches partially.

I tried find() method. But it matches only if the word is exact match.

code:

```
import re
body  = 'Charles D�Silva  |  Technical Officer  Anglo (UK) Limited'
word = 'ANGLO (UK) LTD'
start_idx = body.lower().find(word.lower())
print(match.start())
```

So my output should be, need to get the start index of **Anglo (UK) Limited** in sentence and also need to get the word that partially matches in the sentence (Anglo (UK) Limited).

Any suggestions for the above issue?

Comment: `Ltd` is different than `Limited`. You may want to try [tag:nlp]

Answer (score 2):

This solution assesses how many words are found in both strings, and prints the index if the number of words found meets a threshold.

The 'match_threshold' variable is set so that if 3 words are given, only 2 need to be found. The included max() function assures that the threshold will always be at least 1.

```
body = 'Charles D�Silva  |  Technical Officer  Anglo (UK) Limited'
word = 'ANGLO (UK) LTD'

# Split 'word' into list of strings.
words_to_find = word.lower().split()

# Create list of words that are found in both strings
found_words = [_ for _ in words_to_find if _ in body.lower()]

# Initialize match_threshold
match_threshold = max(len(words_to_find) - 1, 1)

if len(found_words) >= match_threshold:
    found_index = body.lower().index(found_words[0])
    print(found_index)
```

Note: This solution accounts for capitalization, but is otherwise sensitive to typos. Also, words found out of place (such as if "anglo" was part of someone's name in the 'body' string) will produce false positives.

Comment: For Python, there's also the [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) library which finds word distance based on [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and supports partial match. The treshold is character based rather than word based, but can help account for typos when matching.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by making a function that iterates through `body`, and checks if it is the character is equal to the specific letter in the substring `word`. At the first occurence it saves the index to the variable `first_match`. At the end of the function it returns `first_match` if the entire substring is found, and else the `default` parameter.

This **doesn't** return `39`, the start index of `"Anglo (UK) Limited"`, as the `'a'` already exists in `"Charles"`. There isn't any logic (i can think of) to apply that returns `39`, while still succeeding in finding `"Limited"` as `"LTD"` .

```py
def find_partial_match(string: str, substring: str, default: None | int = None) -> int | None:
    iterator = 0
    first_match = None

    # Iterates through string to find if it matches substring[index]
    for index, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == substring[iterator]:
            if iterator == 0:
                first_match = index
            iterator += 1

    # Return the index if everything has matched, else `default`
    return first_match if iterator == len(substring) else default


body = 'Charles D�Silva  |  Technical Officer  Anglo (UK) Limited'
word = 'ANGLO (UK) LTD'
print(find_partial_match(body.lower(), word.lower()))
```